# Use COM Object from DLL without register

Tags: c++, dll, com

Is it possible to use COM Object from DLL without register in C++ not managed code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, if it does not rely internally on other registered objects.

1. You `LoadLibrary` the DLL
2. You `GetProcAddress` its `DllGetClassObject`
3. You call `DllGetClassObject` to obtain `IClassFactory` pointer for `CLSID` of interest
4. You are good to go with `IClassFactory::CreateInstance` and instantiate the coclass

Comment: 2 ½. Make sure you're in the correct apartment before calling `DllGetClassObject`.  Even so, you won't get marshaling for the specific object model interfaces.  Even if the C++ COM objects implement `IMarshal` or `IProvideClassInfo` themselves, you'll need to do the same if you're the one providing objects that implement any of those interfaces (e.g. event dispinterfaces).  For these reasons and many other, this is bad practice.  You should use registration free COM instead.

Answer (score 8):

You can create manifest files for the DLL and use [Registration-Free COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms973913.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

Say, the COM DLL needs to be registered, but the application doesn't have admin access rights. Here is an easy hack to register the DLL under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, which doesn't require admin rights:

1. Use `LoadLibrary` to load the COM DLL.
2. Call `GetGetProcAddress` to get the address of [`DllRegisterServer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682162%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
3. Call [`RegOverridePredefKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to make the temporary registry redirects: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`.
4. Call `DllRegisterServer` obtained in step 2.
5. Reverse the registry redirects.
6. Use the COM server as usual, it's now registered under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.

Comment: "easy" hack. Clever though.

Comment: The [`RegOverridePredefKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regoverridepredefkey) documentation says that the new `HKEY` cannot be one of the predefined keys, so I'm not sure how to proceed with step 3. Should I open an existing registry key then?

Comment: I ended up using an answer [for another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44416524/14227825) and had success calling [`OaEnablePerUserTLibRegistration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-oaenableperusertlibregistration) before `DllRegisterServer`. Only needed to map `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`. I might be missing something however.