# Webbrowser Active X custom dynamic MIME handler pdf

Tags: c++, webbrowser-control, activex

I am using Microsoft's Web Browser ActiveX control in an MFC application.
I want to be able to change the default MIME handler for PDF.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms775148(v=vs.85).aspx

It appears to me that web browser control must use the registry based file type association

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\application/pdf

I want to be able to set web browser control to use the pdf application 
I tell it to use at runtime, rather than using the system registered default.

I cannot find any API that will allow me to do this. Is it possible?

Comment: Probably do-able but tedious, using [Asynchronous Pluggable Protocols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767743%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: ok - thanks. I will accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially proposed in the comments to create an [Asynchronous Pluggable Protocol handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767743%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to customize the player for this MIME type, but I think there might be an easier approach.

You might be able to redirect the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\application/pdf` registry key to your own custom version (per-process) with `RegOverridePredefKey` API, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28448176/1768303).